# How to get value from gradle.properties in .class file at the time of build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, .class-file, gradle.properties

I would like to get a property value from Gradle.properties in Java class.
In Java, the value should be replaced at build time, and in the .jar(.class) file the value will come but not in a .java file. So that we can change the value directly in gradle.properties and no need to change the code.
Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you told your specific use case.
Also it would help to know your application, for example is it a Spring (Boot) app? In that case it would probably make more sense to use Spring Profiles for that.

Anyway, here is a possible solution:

- Create a properties file and put it in your resources folder. Define a placeholder, that gradle can replace. For example file "myapp.properties"

  ```
  greetingText=@greeting@
  ```
- Add the token (the text between the '@'s) to your gradle.properties:

  ```
  greeting=Hello world!
  ```
- Make the build.gradle replace the token with the value from gradle.properties by configuring the processResources task:

  ```
  processResources {
      inputs.file file('gradle.properties')
      filter(
              ReplaceTokens, 
              tokens: [
                      greeting: project.ext.greeting
              ]
      )
  ```

  }
- At runtime load the value from the properties file:

  ```
  public String getGreeting() throws IOException {
      try (
          InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myapp.properties").openStream();
      ) {
          Properties appProps = new Properties();
          appProps.load(inputStream);
          return appProps.getProperty("greetingText");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But is there any way to update the value directly from gradle.properties to java class?

Comment: Well, you _could_ either preprocess the Java source code or after compilation manipulate the byte code with a tool like ByteBuddy, cglib, or javassist to manipulate the byte code of the compiled class, but that seems to be a big hack.